# Using Twilio, can I create numbers on my account for a client using API?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

If I am trying to offer a service for people to call the seller on my site, without using their number, but can I use Twilio API to let the buyer be get a number on my account. And I can set a limit on how many messages they can sent, and have complete control over the number that is created.

Comment: In terms of controlling how many messages a users sends, they would still send the messages through your application, so you would be in control of that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can manage numbers with API calls.

- https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223182728-Using-the-API-to-search-for-and-buy-Twilio-phone-numbers

For example:

You can search for available numbers

- https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers

You can add a new phone number to your account

- https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers#local-incomingphonenumber-factory-resource

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alex. I also wrote a blog post on how you purchase Twilio numbers with Ruby which might help: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/03/search-buy-twilio-phone-numbers-ruby.html.